# Amazonの注文履歴履歴サイトのページ要素が取得できません

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, amazon

最近Pythonの勉強を始め、webスクレイピングを練習中です。そこでAmazonの注文履歴を集計しようと考え、Jupiter labでプログラムを書くことにしました。

1. AmazonのトップページのURLを開く
2. ログインする
3. 注文履歴を開くボタンをクリックする
4. 注文履歴内のデータを取得する

この手順で進めていく予定でしたが、4つ目のデータ取得でrequestとBeautifulSoupを使って

```
history_url = browser.current_url
res = requests.get(history_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
```

と書き、確認のためsoup.titleでタイトルを確認したところ

Amazonサインイン
と言う結果になってしまいました。本来であれば「注文履歴」となって欲しかったのです。

試したこと
request_htmlのrenderをつかってページのHTMLを生成してみるも同じ結果となりました。

プログラミング自体2ヶ月目の初心者で、説明が不十分、コードがむちゃくちゃといったことがあるかと思いますが、回答の方よろしくお願いします。

````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep 

#配列や変数の定義
data = []
MAIL = '*****'
PASS = '*****'
#ヘッドレスモード実装
    #options = Options()
    #options.add_argument('--headless')
#ブラウザを開いてリンクに飛ぶ
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.amazon.co.jp/ap/signin '....(Amazonトップページurl)
browser.get(url)

#ログインボックスに情報を入力
element = browser.find_element_by_id("ap_email")
element.clear()
element.send_keys(MAIL)

login_user = browser.find_element_by_id('continue')
login_user.click()
sleep(2)
element = browser.find_element_by_id('ap_password')
element.clear()
element.send_keys(PASS)
login_pass = browser.find_element_by_id('signInSubmit')
login_pass.click()
sleep(1)
try:
    mobile_skip = browser.find_element_by_id('ap-account-fixup-phone-skip-link')
    mobile_skip.click()
except:
    pass
sleep(1)

#注文履歴ボタンをクリック
elem_order = browser.find_element_by_id('nav-orders')
elem_order.click()

#注文履歴ページのhtml情報を取得
history_url = browser.current_url
res = requests.get(history_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser') ```
````

Comment: コード中にアカウントとパスワードが載っていますが、大丈夫ですか？

Comment: ひとまず編集で表向きには見えないようにしておきましたが、履歴には残ったままですので "完全な削除" がもし必要な場合はお知らせください。 参考Q&A: [公開してはいけない情報を質問や回答として投稿してしまいました。どうすれば良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3004)

Comment: AmazonはJavaScriptが動作する環境でないと難しいようですね。[SeleniumとHeadless ChromeでAmazonの注文履歴を取得する](https://orangain.hatenablog.com/entry/amazon-order-history) `requests`では出来無さそうです。[Using python Requests with javascript pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26393231/9014308)

Comment: 対象サイト( https://www.amazon.co.jp )はスクレイピングしても良いサイトでしょうか？利用規約によると「ロボットなどのデータ収集・抽出ツールの使用」は禁止されているようですが質問のコードは問題ないでしょうか？

Comment: こんな記事があるようです。[【※絶対に自動化してはいけない】自動化禁止サイトまとめ！](https://qiita.com/n_oshiumi/items/b4efd1f40ec0a1b77376), [スクレイピングの倫理①海外のトラブル事例](https://qiita.com/umihico/items/bab223a959d8cfa7b11f) とは言え、「自分自身の注文履歴」を入手するだけなのに「利用規約を盾にプログラムによるアクセスを許さない」のはどうかと思いますが、今までの世間の常識からは仕方の無いことかもしれません。ただし、こんなプログラムが堂々と公開・利用されているようですが。[アマゾン注文履歴フィルタ](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%9E%E3%82%BE%E3%83%B3%E6%B3%A8%E6%96%87%E5%B1%A5%E6%AD%B4%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BF/jaikhcpoplnhinlglnkmihfdlbamhgig?hl=ja)

Comment: ちなみに上記コメントのアマゾン注文履歴フィルタで、Amazonの仕様変更で使えなくなったかもという記事があり、質問の問題を解決しても情報は取れないかもしれませんね。[【お知らせ】アマゾン注文履歴フィルタが突然使えなくなるかもしれません！！](https://memo.furyutei.work/entry/20201226/1608940429)